# List dependencies and repositories in Play Framework

Tags: build, playframework, dependencies, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a play 2.0 project with dependencies. I would like to know what repository each dependency comes from.

Can I list dependencies with their respective repos using the `play` command or SBT?

Comment: There is nothing about that in the PlayCommands.scala for sbt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it looks like there is no way to list repositories the dependencies are coming from. I have sent a question to the Play Google Group, waiting for moderation. I will update the answer if I learn something new.